# Is there a perf hit using mule as a container vs. standard JEE container like Weblogic?

Tags: performance

Our team is considering using Mule in a large scale medium volume internal facing transactional banking application.

At first Mule would just be used as an application server although it is possible some of its esb/orchestration features would be used in the future.

I have no experience with mule, being new on the team. But my gut says Mule would not be as performant as Weblogic or Glassfish as a deployment container.

Does anyone have any comparison stories to share that might shed light?

Comment: What does your profiler say? :)

Answer (score 2):

It's largely impossible to determine performance without actually measuring - I can't say that I've noted WebLogic or Glassfish applications to suddenly become "high performance" simply because of the container.

A few other items you might want to consider (after I took a look at Mule deployment):

- Mule appears to be capable of running 'standalone' (assuming running a process from a JVM?) or within a container (like Glassfish, etc. - seems to be a 'web container' app.)  You might want to look at the pros/cons of running Mule in standalone vs. container.
- There does seem to be quite a bit of clustering / load balancing available with Mule - you might also want to consider how easy it is to set up and monitor clustered applications versus WebLogic/Glassfish.
- You might also take a look at how apps are 'deployed' with Mule - that part wasn't immediately clear when scanning the documentation.